# como aplicar un bucle for con filtros y dobles filtros

Tags: python, bucle-for, filtro

tengo un df con la valoracion, el titulo y el sexo de los que han valorado una pelicula (hay muchos mas datos, las peliculas se repiten por que hay muchas valoraciones de usuarios, lo he simplificado para que sea mas visible)

```
df


    Rating  Title                                   Gender
0   5       One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)  F
1   3       James and the Giant Peach (1996)        M
2   3       My Fair Lady (1964)                     F
3   4       Erin Brockovich (2000)                  F
4   5       Bug's Life, A (1998)                    M
5   3       One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)  M
... ...     ...                                     ...
```

Debo hacer una funcion que me devuelva un df con la media de las valoraciones de los usuarios por pelicula y separados por el sexo, es decir deberia quedar algo asi (con estructura de df o no, como este ejemplo):

```
media_valoraciones():
    "Calcula la puntuación media  de cada película por sexo del usuario"

        media_por_sexo                               Media_mujer    Media_hombre

        titulo 

        One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)       3.375000       2.761905
        James and the Giant Peach (1996)             3.388889       3.352941
        My Fair Lady (1964)                          2.675676       2.733333
        ...                                          ...            ...
```

estoy intentando hacer bucles con `for` de este estilo:

```
for i in df.Title.unique():

    df[df.Title == i].Rating.sum()/len(df[df.Title == i])
```

yo lo leeria como: para cada elemento de los valores unicos de los titulos, haz un filtro en el que para cada uno, sumes las valoraciones y dividelo entre el numero de valoraciones, no me devuelve nada. No se si voy por el camino adecuado.

Tambien deberia de hacer el filtro del sexo, para ello pretendo hacer primero el filtro por sexo y posteriormente aplicar el bucle de arriba, para el filtro del sexo no tengo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas un ciclo, usa `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, agrupa por título y género, aplica la media a cada grupo y desapila para llevarte el multiindex a columnas:

```
medias = (df.groupby(by=["Title", "Gender"])["Rating"]
            .mean()
            .unstack()
            .rename({'F': 'Media_mujer', 'M': 'Media_hombre'}, axis=1)
            )
```

Un ejemplo completo:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\
Rating;Title;Gender
5;One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975);F
3;James and the Giant Peach (1996);M
3;My Fair Lady (1964);F
4;Erin Brockovich (2000);F
5;Bug's Life, A (1998);M
6;One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975);M
3;One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975);F
4;James and the Giant Peach (1996);M
7;My Fair Lady (1964);F
9;Erin Brockovich (2000);M
2;Bug's Life, A (1998);F
6;One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975);F
4;One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975);M
3;James and the Giant Peach (1996);M
2;My Fair Lady (1964);M
6;Erin Brockovich (2000);M
8;Bug's Life, A (1998);M
5;One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975);F
""")


df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";")


medias = (df.groupby(by=["Title", "Gender"])["Rating"]
            .mean()
            .unstack()
            .rename({'F': 'Media_mujer', 'M': 'Media_hombre'}, axis=1)
            )
```

> ```
> >>> medias
>
> Gender                                 Media_mujer    Media_hombre
> Title     
> Bug's Life, A (1998)                         2.00         6.500000
> Erin Brockovich (2000)                       4.00         7.500000
> James and the Giant Peach (1996)              NaN         3.333333
> My Fair Lady (1964)                           5.00        2.000000
> One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)        4.75        5.000000
> ```